# Proving $x^2$ is surjective

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Prove that $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty): x\mapsto x^2$ is surjective.
I'm guessing this is quite elementary, but the catch is:
I don't want to use the continuity theorems (intermediate value thm., min-max thm., and extreme value thm.)or limits at all for that matter.
Also, I defined the square root of a number as an inverse (thus implicitly assuming its existence i.e. the surjectivity of the function defined above).
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: After a bit of thinking, I think it boils down to: Show that $x^2=a$ can be solved for all non-negative $a$ without using square roots.

Comment: It's only "quite elementary" in the sense of relying in an essential way on completeness of the real numbers but not requiring continuity theorems in generality. As Element118 says, you'll have to show every non-negative real number has a real square root, a fact that does not follow from the ordered field axioms alone.

Comment: Doesn't seem easy to prove this without using any property that distinguishes $\mathbb R$ from $\mathbb Q$. Unless you're happy to accept this one: any nonempty bounded subset $X$ of $\mathbb R$ has $\sup X\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: thanks, actually the reason for this is that I started proving stuff about absolute values using square roots, and remembered that it would end up being circular, so the upper bound property, pretty much solves my problems

Answer (score 1):

At some point you will need to use limits. After all, multiplication in $\Bbb R$ is defined by taking rational sequences and multiplying them (so that the product is the limit of this sequence). Using limits is really the right way to answer your question.

Comment: You don't have to *take* the limits; you just need to know that the reals have the least upper bound property.  Hunter's answer follows.  So, yes, you have to know limits exist and work but you don't have to know what they are.

Comment: @fleablood How do you show that the reals have the least upper bound property though? You don't actually compute limits when you use limit theorems either, by the way.

Comment: " How do you show that the reals have the least upper bound property though?"  Because that's the f###ing definition of reals.  I'm in agreement with you, by the way.  He said he didn't want to "use" limits.  You kind of don't have to but you do have to use the idea of limits.

Comment: @fleablood Ok, if that's your definition of the reals, then how do you show that such a field exists at all?

Comment: *I* don't do any such thing at all  I refer to my analysis class and text.  Now and then I'll post a long winded post outlying the concepts of Dedekind cuts (non-empty sets of rational numbers such that is one rational number is in a set all smaller rationals are too and such that a cut has no largest element) and pointing out that cuts being subsets of other cuts forms an order field of cuts that has the least upper bound property and the cuts equivalent to the rationals is a subfield, but after the third or fourth time I just state it as a given and let the OP research it himself.

Comment: You do have to use *something* though  But definitions of reals (whether your definition is via limits or upper bound properties) *has* to be used as this *isn't* true for anything "less" than the reals.  It's a bit much for the OP to say he wants to show this but doesn't want to use any of the real tools available to do so

Answer (score 1):

Let $ a $ be a positive real number. Let $ S $ be the set of real numbers whose square is less than $ a $. Then $ S $ is nonempty (it contains zero) and has an upper bound, so it has a least upper bound, $ b $. Show that $ b^2 = a $.